# Renaming files with powershell to remove a string

Tags: powershell

I have a bunch of files with the same string in them and would like to remove them

```
Dir | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace " (my string here)","" }
```

However, this does not seem to be removing the string from all the files that have that string in the file name. Do I need ReGex?

There is a space before the ( which makes me think I need ReGex in some way.

Answer (score 1):

So I was right about needing ReGex with how Powershell does stuff:

```
Dir | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace "(\s*) \(STRING HERE\)","" }
```

Answer (score 1):

`-replace` does indeed use regex(case-insensitive).
You can achieve the same result without regex with the use of the `.replace` which is a `string` method like so:

```
Get-ChildItem -path 'your path' | 
Rename-Item -NewName { $_.BaseName.replace(' (my string here)','') + $_.extension } -WhatIf
```

notice the use of `$_.basename` instead of `name`. this is because name consists of both filename and extension whereas basename does not.